# Simulation and Histogram of Random Hopping in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, histogram, simulation

I explain you my problem:

Imagine you have a bar, with say s positions. Each position can be counted as position 0, position 1, .. , position s-1.
Now what I want to do is simulate the following : At a certain point in time, a number of particles, say n particles, start in a state of the bar (assume a position in the middle).
At this point with random probabilities pr and pl (pr + pl =1) this particles go right or left respectively. So basically the probability reflects the proportion of particles swapping right or left.

I want to repeat this a number of times and see what is the final position of the particles and plot an histogram of it.
This is my function hop, which I made in order to simulate the hopping of the particles.

```
def hop(n):
'''
n is the number of particles starting in the middle position.
'''

s = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,n,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
global ls
ls = len(s)
i = 0

while i < 100:
    for j in range(0,int(len(s))):
        if s[j] != 0 :
            pr = random.random()
            pl = 1 - pr
            if j - 1 < 0:
                s[j+1] = s[j+1]+int(s[j]*pr)
                s[j] = s[j] - int(s[j]*pr)
            elif len(s) <= j+1:
                s[j-1] = s[j-1] + int(s[j]*pl)
                s[j] = s[j] - int(s[j]*pl)
            else:
                s[j-1] = s[j-1] + int(s[j]*pl)
                s[j+1] = s[j+1] + int(s[j]*pr)
                s[j] = s[j] - int(s[j]*pr) - int(s[j]*pl)
            j+=1
        elif s[j] == 0:
            s[j] = 0
            j+=1
    i+=1
return s
```

And here is the rest, that I used to plot the histogram:

```
x = hop(100)
y = sum(x) #This is for debugging purposes, I want to check that I'm left 
           with the right number of particles
list1 = []
for k in range(0,ls):
    list1.append(k)
plt.hist(x,list1)
plt.show()
```

Where I have imported mathplotlib and specifically I've imported

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
```

My problem is that from the histograms that I obtain this is doing something very wrong. Indeed the histograms are all skewed to the left, which wouldn't be possible If the probabilities are taken at random.
Furthermore the histogram doesn't show me the right amounts of particles.

Does anyone understand what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think the main mistake might be in the histogram. The point is that I want an histogram which shows me how many particles there are in each state at the end. So the x-axis would represents all the states, while the y axis would represent the density of particles! But I get it wrong

Comment: Cause I think that so far what my code is doing, is simply counting how many times a certain number of particles occupy a state and plotting this as the height of the histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i got you right, but
do you want to see this instead of a histogram?

```
xs = np.arange(len(x))
width = 1/1.5
plt.bar(xs,x,width)
```

Comment: No problem, the barchart plots each column together with its value you calculated in the hop function. The histogram puts these values into bins and plots their distribution. Thats why you end up with any smaller values and fewer high values as you said. Have a look at the list x in the variable explorer and check its values. Lukas

Comment: Do you think it is sensible that after many repetitions it gets messy and without any recognisable pattern?